# Verify if a Linux host is controlled by the Kubernetes orchestration platform

Tags: linux, docker

The docker info command indicates if a node is controlled by the Swarm orchestration platform:

```
sudo docker info:
```

```
…
Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: active
NodeID: rdjq45w1op418waxlairloqbm
…
```

There is any similar way to get the same information for Kubernetes?